# How to calculate the condition of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, condition-number

The terms

$a(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{1+2x}-\dfrac{1-2x}{1+x}$ and $b(x)=\dfrac{3x^2}{(1+2x)(1+x)}$ are for $x>0$ the same function $f(x)$.

Calculate the condition of $f$ for $0<|x|\ll 1$.

How would one preceed when evaluating $f(x)$ for $0<|x|\ll 1$ to garantuee good numerical stability?

---

I want to calculate the condition of $f$. I would do so by using the formula

$\displaystyle{\left|\frac{f'(x)x}{f(x)}\right|}=\left|\frac{3x+2}{1+3x+2x^2}\right|$

For the condition of $f$, we then get $\operatorname{cond}(f)(0)=2$ and $\operatorname{cond}(f)(1)=\frac56$. So a bad condition around 0 and a good condition around 1.

Question: Is this correct, because I do not see how the different expressions of $f$ can be used here, as there is no real change, when applying the formula. So I think this does not matter here.

From the lecture notes I do not see why it should be justified to use the formula for the condition on each summand $\frac{1-x}{1+2x}$ and $-\frac{1-2x}{1+x}$ seperatly and then "add" the results.

With other words: How can a different expression help?

If I do this however I would get that for the term $\frac{1-x}{1+2x}$ there is a good condition around $0$ and a terrible condition around $1$ as the term tends to $\infty$ for $x\to 1$.

For the other term $-\frac{1-2x}{1+x}$ I would also get a good condition around $0$ and a condition of 3/2 around $1$.

So I do not see how this would help here.

Can you comment on the topic of condition and stability, as I find this kind off unclear in my lecture notes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't confuse condition and stability. The condition number cannot distinguish $a(x)$ from $b(x)$, nor can you add or subtract condition numbers, because it s not linear. You need to decompose each expression in elementary steps (they are not the same in $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ and account for the roundoff errors in each step.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I do not understand what I have to do then. Can you give a reference or the method on what has to be calculated now? I am pretty sure that is how the condition is defined in my notes, so I do not understand how I confused it with stability....

Comment: The condition number "explains" how errors in the arguments are propagated by the function. So, since $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are exactly the same function they have the exact same behaviour with this respect. If your notes expect you to distinguish $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ from the condition number they are just wrong. Stability requires conditioning, but also involves the propagation of intermediate errors during the calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Maybe my brain has a malfunction, but I didnt see your answer, when I wrote my comment above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition number by itself does not establish the numerical stability. When you have different algorithms for computing $f(x)$, in this case $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ suggest two equivalent ways of computing $f(x)$, they cannot be distinguished based on the condition number (which will be the same) but rather by the way they propagate roundoff errors introduced at each step of the algorithm. In each case you can write the relative error of the final result as
$$
\varepsilon_f = \textrm{cond}_f(x) \varepsilon_x + \sum_{i=1}^n Q_i(x) \varepsilon_i
$$

and you say the the algorithm is numerically stable near some $x$ if both the condition number and the coefficients $Q_i$ are bounded. So, in the case of $a(x)$, you would have, for instance
$$
z_1 = \frac{1-x}{1+2x}, \quad z_2 = \frac{1-2x}{1+x}, \quad z_3 = z_1-z_2
$$
and so,
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{z_1} = & -\frac{3 x}{-2 x^2+x+1}\varepsilon_x + \varepsilon_1\\
\varepsilon_{z_2} = & \frac{1}{2 x-1} \varepsilon_x + \varepsilon_2\\
\varepsilon_{z_3} = & \frac{z_1\cdot 1}{z_1-z_2}\varepsilon_{z_1}+\frac{z_1\cdot (-1)}{z_1-z_2}\varepsilon_{z_2} + \varepsilon_{3}
\end{align*}

If you substitute $\varepsilon_{z_1}, \varepsilon_{z_2}$ in the last expression, you can observe the behaviour of coeficients for different ranges of $x$.

If you repeat the procedure for $b(x)$, you'll be able to compare.